# Kill roscore and all nodes when rosbag play finishes?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm writing some automated test scripts. I'd like to run a launch script with a bag file, which works fine. But when the rosbag play completes I would like roslaunch to exit so my script can load up a new bag file and rerun roslaunch with the test.launch file. Is there an elegant way to cause all ros nodes and roscore to exit when a bag file is finished? I was thinking of making another script to monitor when rosbag finished and then execute a rosnode kill, but I thought there might be a better way.

Thanks,
Jason

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12751/kill-roscore-and-all-nodes-when-rosbag-play-finishes?/) by [Jason LaPenta](https://answers.ros.org/users/1603/jason-lapenta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-01-25**:
This is tangential, but you may want to look into using rostest to bring your test fixture up and down using roslaunch files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're running all your nodes from the same launch file as the bag, just add required="true" to the node tag for rosbag. This will cause the entire roslaunch to die when rosbag terminates.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-02**:
When you get a good/the best answer please use the checkbox to the left to mark it as answered.  I've done so for you this time.

**Comment by [Jason LaPenta](https://answers.ros.org/users/1603/jason-lapenta/) on 2012-01-25**:
this appears to work perfectly, thanks

**Comment by [Roger Yau](https://answers.ros.org/users/25015/roger-yau/) on 2015-11-06**:
typo: required = 'true'

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried this, but perhaps something like this:

```
rosbag play foo.bag; rosnode kill -a
```

---

Originally posted by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) with karma: 1607 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) on 2014-10-22**:
rosnode kill -a kind of works but sometimes not all nodes get killed